# How do I make an NFS mount have the same owner across multiple targets?

Tags: linux, nfs

I have a data server `dataserver` that mounts via NSF to several Ubuntu VMs (a mixture of 16.04 and 20.04).

The target VMs mount the directory by a systemd unit file

```
[Unit]
Description=/mountpoint
Wants=network-online.target
After=network-online.target

[Mount]
What=dataserver:/origin/folder
Where=/mountpoint
Type=nfs
Options=nofail,rw,soft,intr,actimeo=60

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

On the target VMs, the mounted files show up as being owned by different users.  In some cases, /mountpoint/ is owned by `utility:utgroup`, a utility user/group that we've defined and that we *want* to own these files.  On these VMs, `utility:utgroup` have UID/GID `999:999`.

On other VMs, however, the mounted files show up as being owned by `systemd-coredump:systemd-coredump`.  On these VMs, that user/group is what has UID/GID `999:999`, and `utility:utgroup` has something else.

It seems like the NFS source is being mounted by UID/GID, and the target VMs filter that into whatever user and group use those IDs locally.

I'd like to make `utility:utgroup` the owner of the mounted files on all VMs.  The most obvious way is to move `systemd-coredump` to a different UID/GID on all VMs where it's now 999, and then move `utility:utgroup` to that UID/GID.  Messing with the IDs of a systemd utility user/group seems like inviting disaster, however.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27769444/6673905) to a somewhat similar problem suggests using `/etc/nfs.map` to map IDs, but evidently that's an older method that no longer works.  I tried it myself, and it did not change the users on the VMs that have the wrong user:group ownership.

What is the safest way to make `utility:utgroup` the owner on all VMs?

Comment: NFSv4 works differently from NFSv3 here. If you filesystem is mounted as nfs4 (check /proc/mounts, as stating nfs can still get nfs4 chosen in the end) you should add the nfs4 tag, so people able to answer this will know it. Else mention you're on NFSv3, not v4.

Comment: Just an FYI, Ubuntu 16.04 is only supported for another week, then is EOL and will not receive any support. I recommend upgrading ASAP.